# How to format PreserveText in phpoffice / phpword

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

Using PHPOffice/PHPWord, I'd like to format the page numbers in my footer so that the numbers are bold, and rest of the text is plain, like this:

Page **3** of **10**

At the moment I've got:

```
$footer->addPreserveText('Page {PAGE} of {SECTIONPAGES}', 'footerFont', 'footerPara');
```

Which works absolutely fine, except it'll only let me style the whole sentence, not the individual numbers.

I've tried using a textRun to break up the styling, but I get this error:

```
"Cannot add PreserveText in TextRun"
```

A textRun, on static text, works find in the footer; I can add to it using `addText` but NOT using `addPreserveText`.

How can I style my page numbers differently from the surrounding text so that I get **bold** numbers like in "Page **2** of **5**"?

This question could take another route: "Is it possible to add page/section numbers using `addText` rather than `addPreserveText`?"

*I have phpword version: 0.17.0 installed*